# Outlook Create Folders Automatically Based on Subject / Content

Tags: vba, outlook

Was wondering if there any way I can make Microsoft Outlook to automatically create Folder  and name it based on the subject line / body of the mail once an incoming mail is received.

Answer (score 1):

You should look in to using [Rules](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-rules-outlook-and-take-back-your-inbox) in Outlook. You can create a folder, and set conditions in which emails form a certain user, with certain contents, or whatever other conditions you want to set, and it will give the option to retroactively put all those emails into that folder, as well as do it for all future emails. The best part is, no VBA required!

Answer (score -1):

Here is some of my test code:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private inboxFolders As Outlook.Folder

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set inboxFolders = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
End Sub


Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim MessageInfo
  Dim Result
  If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    MsgBox ("try to add new folder: " & Item.Subject)
    'add a for loop to check existing folders for name here
    inboxFolders.Folders.Add (Item.Subject)
    Item.Move inboxFolders.Folders(Item.Subject)
  End If
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description`enter code here`
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

Make sure to enable macros (add developer tab and change macro security setting)

This code will move new emails into a folder named after the subject. Add a few lines of code to see if the folder name already exists.

I got a lot of this from: https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/